# How to select rows from two tables using sql

Tags: sql

I want to select rows from table A where `UserId=1` and table B where `UserName=xxx`.

If the rows from A and B are same, we can use group.

**Table A**

```
Session    UserId
-----------------
1           1
2           2
```

**Table B**

```
Session    Username
-------------------
1           xxx
11          xxx
12          xxx
```

**User table**

```
UserId    Username
------------------
1         xxx
```

Now I want to get rows from table a `where userid = 1` and from table b `where username = xxx`. If the session from a and b are same, we can group it.

```
Session
==========
1
11
12
```

Answer (score 3):

> Now I want to get rows from table a where userid = 1 and from table b where username = xxx. If the session from a and b are same, we can group it.

It sounds to me like you are asking for the `union` of the filtered `session` values from the two tables, and as you want the distinct set, you do want `union` rather than `union all` (`union all` is actually a much more common requirement than `union`):

```sql
select session from table_a where userid = 1
union
select session from table_b where username = xxx
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,
sorry if any syntactically errors.

```
SELECT A.UserId, B.Username FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.Session= B.Session GROUP BY A.Session;
```

it will retrieves all records that match the session from both the table i.e. A and B.

Now, include your additional conditions to existing query. something like this...

```
SELECT A.UserId, B.Username FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.Session= B.Session 
WHERE A.UserId = 1 AND B.Username = 'xxx' GROUP BY A.Session;
```

Hope it will helps you. Thanks. !!

Comment: Using `WHERE A,B` (old syntax) is not recomendad instead `use table JOIN`.

Comment: Kaf, marc_s : Thanks for such a good information. Now onwords i always use JOINS. I have also edited my answer for reliable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following is `TSql` for SQL Server. Also try to learn about `table JOIN`. Here are [some good examples](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

```
SELECT A.Session, A.UserId
FROM A JOIN B ON A.Session = B.Session --Joining A and B using Session here
WHERE A.UserId = 1 AND B.Username = 'xxx'
```

Answer (score -1):

Mysql has a way of doing this. [Check out this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

---

Best I'll do:

```
SELECT `table1`.`column`, `table2`.`column` FROM `table1`, `table2` WHERE conditon
```

Comment: I'll point you in the right direction... [Tutorial](http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/select-two-mysql-tables_t)

Comment: @marc_s Don't we all first learn to crawl before walking? Learning the old eases the transition to the new.